# How to include VCS information in setuptools packages

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm (trying) to use setuptools to build a package. I was trying to use a version number `major.minor.mercurial_revision` but it complains that:

```
The version specified ('1.0.7ae7970a82c1') is an invalid version, this may
not work as expected with newer versions of setuptools, pip, and PyPI.
Please see PEP 440 for more details.`
```

Fine. So I look at PEP 440 which says basically says "don't do that":

```
As hashes cannot be ordered reliably such versions are not permitted in the
public version field. As with semantic versioning, the public  .devN  
suffix may be used to uniquely identify such releases for publication, 
while the original DVCS based label can be stored in the project metadata.
```

I understand the logic here. But how *can* I include the hg revision in the project metadata? I can't find any (up-to-date) documentation for what the arguments to `setup.py:setup()` can include, but the distutils one I found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#additional-meta-data%20here) doesn't seem to provide a field for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [local version identifier](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#local-version-identifiers) to accomplish this.

> Local version identifiers MUST comply with the following scheme:
>
> `<public version identifier>[+<local version label>]`

In your case this would be `<major>.<minor>+<mercurial_version>`, which would result into `1.0+7ae7970a82c1`

Answer (score 0):

What about just including it as an attribute in your Python code?

```
echo '__revision__ = $HG_HASH' > mypackage/revision.py
```

Once installed, you can:

```
from mypackage.revision import __revision__
print 'build from', __revision__
```

Or you could write it to a file, and include that in your source distribution via `MANIFEST.in`.

You could even include it directly in the arguments to `setup()`, which seems to simply ignore unknown keyword arguments:

```
setup(name='Distutils',
      version='1.0',
      description='Python Distribution Utilities',
      author='Greg Ward',
      author_email='gward@python.net',
      url='https://www.python.org/sigs/distutils-sig/',
      packages=['distutils', 'distutils.command'],
      revision='7ae7970a82c1',
     )
```

This doesn't get recorded anywhere, but it is always available by inspection if someone needs to know it for debugging information or something.  Because this relies on `setup()` ignoring unknown arguments -- which I'm not sure is explicitly documented behavior -- I don't know that this idea is actually one I would recommend.

Comment: Because then you've got an untracked file in your sourcecode, which isn't very nice, and your build script has to do the "echo" bit. It's all non-standard and the above answer solves it.

Comment: If you're including revision information in your project -- via `setup.py` or another file -- you are obviously *generating* that file as part of your release process.  So either it's (a) untracked, or (b) you're automatically updating/committing it as part of your release process.

Comment: Hmm. You are of course right. In fact the problems are a bit orthogonal; Remco's answer solves getting distutils to accept my version number, but getting *access* to the version number from "inside" the package needs a `__revision__` or something like you suggest.